# Python module order of execution

Tags: python, methods, nameerror

I have a normally structured Python program with import statements, class definitions, other routines, and some "main" statements that invoke methods in the classes (in that order).  a print statement after the imports prints "ok"

Python 2.7.2

I am getting a nameError in a class method.

```
print >> common, ...

NameError: 'common' is not defined
```

`common` is used earlier in the same method, but the earlier references occasioned no errors.

`common` is used in many methods - moving this method physically has no effect: the error is still on the same line in this method.

The error occurs *before* the method is called, and before any of the "main" statements are executed.  Putting return as the first executable statement in the method has no effect.  This is all apparently happening at class definition time.

If I comment out the `print >> common` statements, I get a different NameError in the same method.

I have no idea how I can get a NameError inside a method at 'definition time'.

Any ideas?  The method is below:

x = z ** 2 below is *supposed* to generate a NameError: there is no z.
A print statement just after all the function definitions is not executed.

```
"""code below"""
 @classmethod
    def show_role_map(cls):
        """show jobs within roles, with total days, with percents of totals"""

        return
        raise ZeroDivisionError
        return

        print >> common, "xyzzy"

        x = z ** 2

        p       = Performance("Traveler: show_role_map")
        print   "\tshow_role_map"
        roles   = cls.role_map.keys()
        roles.sort()
        header  ("Qualitative Role Map")

        role_totals = collections.defaultdict(float)
        job_totals  = collections.defaultdict(float)

        for name in Traveler.roster:
            trav = Traveler.roster[name]
            for day in trav.roles:
                frac = 1.0 / len(trav.roles[day])
                for role in trav.roles[day]:
                    role_totals[role] += frac
            for day in trav.jobs:
                frac = 1.0 / len(trav.jobs[day])
                for job in trav.jobs[day]:
                    job_totals[job] += frac

        role_total  = sum(role_totals.values())
        job_total   = sum(job_totals.values())
        assert abs(role_total - job_total) <= 1e-6

        print >> common, "Total Role days =", role_total
        print >> common, "Total Job  days =", job_total
        print >> common


        for role in roles:
            if role_totals[role] == 0: continue
            print >> common, "\t%12s %51.1f %12s %12.3f" %\
                (role, role_totals[role], \
                "", 100.0 * role_totals[role] / role_total)

            jobs = list(cls.role_map[role])
            jobs.sort (key = lambda x: (job_totals[x], x), reverse = True)

            for index, job in enumerate(jobs, 1):
                if job_totals[job] == 0: continue
                print role, job, role_totals[role], job_totals[job]
                print >> common, "\t\t%6d. %35s %12.1f % 12.3f %12.3f" % \
                    (index, job, job_totals[job], \
                100.0 * job_totals[job] / role_totals[role],
                100.0 * job_totals[job] / role_total)
            print >> common


    print >> common, "\n", "_" * 60, "\n" #--ERROR OCCURS FOR THIS LINE ****************
    print >> common, "\nRoles in Total Tripday order\n"
    roles = role_totals.keys()
    roles.sort (order = lambda x: (role_totals[x], x), reverse = True)
    for index, role, in enumerate(roles,1):
        print >> common, "%6d. %15s %12.1f %12.3f" % \
            (index, role, role_totals[role], \
            100.0 * role_totals[role]/role_total)

    print >> common, "\n", "_" * 60, "\n"
    print >> common, "\nDetailed Trip Roles in Total Tripday order"
    jobs = job_totals.keys()
    jobs.sort (key = lambda x: (job_totals[x], x), reverse = True)
    for index, job in jobs:
        print >> common, "%6d. %35s %12.1f %12.3f" % \
            (index, job, job_totals[job], 100.0 * job_totals[job] / job_total)


    p.close()
```

Comment: I understand the question. But without some code, it's very difficult to tell you where your code diverges from what you expect. Please post your code

Comment: Please include the entire segment (method) of code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Feel free to expect no results without you posting your code. Also,  you might want to tell us what version of python you're using (though that shouldn't be necessary for a while)

Comment: This is a great case for using a python debugger. Just start at the top of the module and single step to see what's being executed.

Comment: @Gerry I don't see where you define the `common` variable in that code example.

Comment: Resolution happens before execution so it's normal. Make sure you get the scope of your variable right. If it's a member of your class, use self.common, if it's a variable in another class, think on how to share it across your methods/functions or whatever. Think about scope.

Answer (score 1):

So first things first. When you define a function, the function is not executed. Only the name is noted in the namespace. Only when the function is called (aka invoked), does it actually execute the code within the function (this is true assuming you have no syntax errors).

So the interpreter handles your imports, etc (at the top of the file) and then notices that you have a function (so it notes its name) and continues executing the rest of the code (the stuff after the function definition). It is at this point that it sees `print >> common`. Since `common` is not on the memory stack (it has never been defined before), the interpreter doesn't know what its value is and therefore raises a `NameError`.

Note that this will still happen when you call your function, as it also uses `common` before it is defined.

Hope this helps

Comment: There are 30+ other methods, defined before this one, that all print >> common

Comment: it doesn't really matter how many methods there are prior to this one, that print `common`. Each function has its own `common` within its scope. Thus, those definitions of common do not affect this one. If that's what you're aiming for, then perhaps you want a global variable or a data member (`self.common`).

Comment: common is global.  It is assigned a file ref, once, in the code after all the function definitions. Think about this method, if common is a NameError on the commented line, why isn't it a name error on the earlier lines in the function that reference common?  e.g., print >> common, "xyzzy"?

Comment: The whole point is that Python is looking at this function at class definition time, and has (can have) no idea of whether common will be defined by the time it's needed.  My point on the other 30 methods was merely that they all have similar use patterns: they print to common, too; and common is instantiated, once, later.

Comment: It's not (yet) a name error on the previous lines because those earlier lines because those lines are in the function scope and are therefore not executed at class-def time. However, the commented line is out of the function's scope and is therefore executed at class-def time. Hence the name error. If you want to use a global variable, make sure that you are using the `global` keyword correctly

Comment: class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        print >> common, "foo!"
        
common = open ("foo.txt", "w")
--- works just the way I'd expect.  This is what I'm trying to do in the original problem method
f = Foo()

Comment: class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        print >> common, "foo!"
        
        if two < one:
            xyzzy += 1
            
        
common = open ("foo.txt", "w")
one = 1
two = 2
f = Foo() -- this runs fine, too, even though xyzzy is never defined

Comment: something doesn't add up here. I think we'll need to see the actual file

Answer (score 0):

Indentation error.  The problem statement was not indented within its function, and thus appeared to be Python as a statement to be executed at class definition time.

Thanks to all who tried to help.